# Efficient way to draw from two distributions to get a specific correlation?

Tags: correlation, sampling

$x$ and $y$ are correlated random variables, but were randomly permuted. Their correlation can be treated as known. What are some efficient ways to draw joint samples that have (close to) the right correlation?

For example, say that the variables are realizations of a process like the following:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- mvrnorm(1000, c(0,0), matrix(c(1, .5, .5, 1), 2))
x <- sample(A[,1], 100)
y <- sample(A[,2], 100)
```

I can estimate from other data the correlation.  So the goal is to form samples of $x$ and $y$ that can get me to a correlation of .5 (or so).  The important thing is that I re-create  a joint distribution with the correct properties.

The actual application involves taking an average of simulates from two distributions that are known to be correlated, but from which the simulates were random.  If I just take a pointwise average of the two distributions, I'll shrink the variance too much.

Here is an inefficient way to do what I want to do:

```
#sort the data
xs <- sort(x)
ys <- sort(y)

rho <- cor(xs, ys)              #current correlation
while (rho >.5){
  pick <- sample(1:100, 1)      #pick a value
  xs <- c(xs[-pick], xs[pick])  #stick it on the end
  rho <- cor(xs, ys)            #update the correlation
  print(rho)                    #verbosity
}
```

Anything more efficient?

EDIT:  Actually, nevermind -- the thing I proposed just now is not good; should have been obvious:

[image]

EDIT2:  Here's another fairly slow way (but fun to watch):

```
rho <- cor(x, y)              #current correlation
while (rho <.5){
  axy <- abs(x-y)
  pick <- sample(1:100, 2, prob = axy/sum(axy))
  re <- x[pick]
  xs <- x
  xs[pick[1]] <- re[2]
  xs[pick[2]] <- re[1]
  testrho <- cor(xs, y)            
  if (testrho > rho){
    x <- xs
    rho <- testrho
    print(rho)
  }
  plot(x,y)
}
```

EDIT3:  Here's a method that uses a normal copula.  It's fast, but its inexact and doesn't guarantee that I'll use all of the values in $x$ and $y$:

```
qdist <- pnorm(mvrnorm(100, c(0,0), matrix(c(1, .5, .5, 1), 2)))
xs <- quantile(x, probs = qdist[,1])
ys <- quantile(y, probs = qdist[,2])
cor(cbind(xs, ys))
```

Comment: Right, but I mean drawing from the values of $x$ and $y$

Comment: It seems to me that you'd probably be better off asking how to solve the underlying problem (how to combine the two simulation results) rather than asking how to better do [your idea for a solution of that problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). [Indeed, if those two simulations are in turn an attempt to solve another problem, it may be better to go back a step further, and so on.]

Comment: @Glen_b Right, I've definitely had thoughts along those lines.  Could I estimate a copula rather than a couple of vectors of simulates?  Could I find a whole different way to incorporate uncertainty in the model output?  Is this whole project just kind of silly?  Why am I doing statistics when I'd be happier as a forest ranger or a farmer?

Comment: Seriously, why not post more information about the underlying problem in your question? It may help convey what you're doing (which is not clear to me, and likely many others). I'd also suggest you avoid code as a way of conveying an algorithm because it conflates two different sources of error (any mistaken ideas about how to solve the problem and any mistakes in implementation of that), making it difficult to disentangle and guess what you intended. It also greatly reduces the number of people able to offer advice because many won't know your chosen language well.